# Finding "internal" diagonals in a matrix (Python)

Tags: python, matrix, internals, diagonal

I need help in trying to find a way (in Python) to collect all "internal" diagonals in a Matrix (i.e. diagonals that do not necessarily start in the edge of the matrix, or end in an edge). For example, I can have the following matrix,

```
M = [
    [10 12 12 16]
    [11 88 16 10]
    [46 44 70 23]
    [11 11 16 10]
    ]
```

where an example output could be,

```
[[88, 70], [88, 70, 10], [16, 23], ...]
```

which corresponds to "internal" diagonals that do not necessarily touch both edges in the matrix, and that go from top left to bottom right. I know that np.diagonal() gets me all diagonals from edge to edge, and that I can specify an offset, but cannot get me those internal diagonals.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question doesnt seem to be phrased correctly, what do you need help on?

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I need help in finding a pythonic way to collect those internal diagonals in the matrix